# Convert Epoch or Unix timestamp to date ANDROID

Tags: android, date, timestamp

I am creating a chat application and I want to print the date and time in chat bubble whenever the message is sent or received.

I used the below code to get and convert the date and time.

```
   long itemLong = (long) (chatMessage.getTime()*1000);
    Date itemDate = new Date(itemLong);
    String itemDateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM HH:MM").format(itemLong);
    holder.time.setText(itemDateStr);
```

The itemLong variable gets the value 1.4847986E15, which is converted to date and timestamp in the format I mentioned in SimpleDateFormat, but eveytime some random date and time gets displayed not at which the message was sent or received.

I tried various solutions but I am unable to get the correct date and time.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are u multiplying with 1000, does getTime returns nanosecconds?

Comment: @AnkushBist I tried the solution provided. But it isn't working for me. :(

Comment: @Rider what not working in that.. be precise.

Comment: chatMessage.getTime() post this data and please provide me the date what it need to return. I will go through this

Comment: @AnkushBist It need to return the current date and time at which the message is sent or received.

Comment: @Doe There's no error or warning, its just I am unable to display the current date and time.

Comment: @Rider then its difficult to help you.

Comment: Is it some system default set UTC problem.?

Comment: @rider add your chatMessage.getTime() actual data in comment here. Then i can try to execute the code

Comment: ChatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited the code to this and its working fine.

```
 long itemLong = (long) (chatMessage.getTime()/1000);
    java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(itemLong*1000L);
    String itemDateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM HH:mm").format(d);
    holder.time.setText(itemDateStr);
```